# Javamail server connection time out

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to a mail server using [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/). I am receiving an exception.

I have tried using POP3 as well, but no luck.

Error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect
```

This was caused by:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

My code:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

try
{
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
    props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
    store.connect(host,user,password);
}
catch (MessagingException ex){
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);
// SSL setting
properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", 
"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", String.valueOf(port));

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
// connects to the message store
Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
store.connect(user, password);
System.out.println(store.isConnected());
System.out.println("connection succesful");

// opens the inbox folder
Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then follow these [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to go establish connection using below. My bad I had used an inappropriate host before.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

    MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);

    props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
    System.out.println("store is "+store.isConnected());

    store.connect("mail.abc.com","xyz@abc.com", "******");
    System.out.println("Now the store  is  "+store.isConnected());
```